# Как отправить с помощью ajax запрос на валидацию формы?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, form

То есть я хочу сделать так: у меня есть форма. Я по ее айдишнику с помощью serialize собираю данные и отправляю постом, но не на php-шный файл, а к плагину jquery-validate, который(естественно) лежит отдельно. Это то, что я могу сделать. А вот в чем загвоздка. По идее там плагин должен обработать данные на вшивость и прислать ответ в виде ошибок, на которые уже должны стоять правила, куда их воткнуть.

я думаю, что структура должна быть такая:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var queryString = $('#validForm').serialize();
    $(''#button).click(function(){
        $.post('/js/validateOptions.js', queryString , 
        function(data) {
            alert('data');
        });
    });
});
```

в коде плагина(т.е. в коде настроек дял плагина я прописываю минимальные требования)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#validForm").validate();
});
```

И мне кажется здесь надо еще указать что-то, что возвращает ответ для моего запроса(или я ошибаюсь?)

Мои вопросы:
Как плагин получит запрос, как обработает его и как пришлет ответ?
Что нужно указать в callback-функции?

P.S. 
Буду рад за полученную консультацию. Не откажусь от ссылки на источники, где можно самостоятельно понять и решить проблему. Также буду рад любому предложенному решению (и желательно объяснению).

http://ajaxvalid.max.i-wendy.ru - мой рабочий ссылка)))))

Answer (score 1):

Извините, но у Вас отсутствует понимание того, что такое клиент, а что такое сервер.. Зачем Вы к JS файлу через POST обращаетесь ? Я что-то сомневаюсь, что у Вас *серверный* код на JS будет написан.
JS-валидация - клиентская. Смысл валидировать данные в JS именно в том, чтобы не делать запросов к серверу без необходимости, таким образом, возможно, повышая эффективность. В общем, [читайте](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/46.html)

Answer (score 0):

бегло глянул  [тут](http://fleek.org/jquery-validaciya-form/) и  [тут](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html) - я так понимаю вам нада прописывать для каждого поля метод валидации (из списка встроенных) или создавать свою функцию и указывать ее. И на скок я понял все ето делается без отправки на сервер а чисто на клиенте - нада просто подкулючать плагин